# On the proof of the maximum principle for elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

From Renardy - "An Introductionto Partial Differential Equations".

Let 
$$Lu=a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}+b_i(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}+c(x)u,\ x\in\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$$

The maximum principle states that for $Lu\ge0$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$ with $c(x)=0$ the maximum of $u$ is achieved on $\partial \Omega$.

The proof is done by contradiction. Suppose $Lu>0$ then $u$ cannot achieve its maximum anywhere in $\Omega$. Suppose it did at a point $x_0$. Then all first derivatives must vanish and one can show that $Lu(x_0)\le 0$, contradiction.

Now (for the case $Lu=0$) an approximation argument is used. Let $u_\epsilon=u+\epsilon\exp(\gamma x_1)$. We obtain
$$Lu_\epsilon = Lu + \epsilon(\gamma^2a_11 + \gamma b_1)\exp(\gamma x_1)$$We can then choose $\gamma$ large enough s.t. $\gamma^2a_11 + \gamma b_1\ge0$

Then $Lu_\epsilon >0$ and we have that $$\max_{\overline \Omega}u_\epsilon = \max_{\partial \Omega}u_\epsilon$$ for every $\epsilon>0$. The theorem follows from $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Now my question is: Why can I assume that this maximum property holds for the limes? It might be possible that when taking the limit, that the limit function does not satisfy this relation anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, hence the added "error part" is uniformly (to $\varepsilon$) bounded (denoted as M). Hence we have the following dominate (note that $u_{\varepsilon}>u$):$$
\max_{\Omega}u\leq \max_{\Omega}u_{\varepsilon}
=\max_{\partial_{\Omega}}u_{\varepsilon}\leq \max_{\partial\Omega}+\varepsilon\cdot M.
$$
The last step comes from $\max(a+b)\leq\max(a)+\max(b)$. Now we take limit and  the result follows immediately.

This is the reason why we demaned $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. This proof doesn't holds for  unbounded $\Omega$. I hope I stated the reason clear.;)

Comment: But since $\Omega$ is open, we need know if the error part does attain its supremum. But since the error part is $\exp(\gamma x_1)$ we can continue this function on a closed set, is this correct?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Well, due to $\Omega$ is bounded, hence the supremum of the "error part" can be dominated by some constant (depending on $\overline{\Omega}$). And it is true that we can do the same process on $\overline{\Omega}$, there are no big differences here. :)